# EF6 - EmailAddress attribute is not validate automatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework Code First, Is there a possibility to automatically validate email address on entities ?

MaxLength attribute return an error message without manually validation but not EmailAddress attribute.

Is it normal ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you decorate your property with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute`?

Comment: I'd suggest doing (@haim770's solution) that in view model instead of the entity model